# How to make scrollbar shown to the tablet user who access the site from small screen devices?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want a simple thing in my site that when someone do browsing on site they can see the content by scrolling them.

Suppose I have a slider that have 100% width then they can see other part of images by scrollbar in bottom of slider. same for left and right content.

Do someone know any trick to apply this. When I write width:100%; overflow:scroll it's not shown anything to user when I tried from small screen.

```
 <div class="slide-images">
                        <div class="slide-img">
                            <img src="assets/img/slide_plumb_01.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-img">
                            <img src="assets/img/slide_plumb_02.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide-img">
                            <img src="assets/img/slide_plumb_03.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Tablets/phones usually don't show the scrollbar until you begin scrolling and it goes away once you stop. Because of the smaller screen, you can't waste any space on a scrollbar. You'd have to write one yourself if you really wanted to, but I don't see the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `width: 100%;` it means it's `100%` to the viewport so I wonder how this fails for you, instead of `%` use `em`, also scrolling is available by default if your page exceeds the height and width of the viewport, unless and until you use `overflow: hidden;` and if you want different styles for screens and devices use CSS3 `@media queries`

Syntax

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 240px) { /* You can set the
                                                              resolutions here
                                                           */
  /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Here's a nice article to [get started](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) with media queries

Comment: @alien, sorry, but I not want to write media queries in my project. I just want to write a hack that shown the scrollbar in bottom and user can use scroller to scroll

Comment: @user2126670 Why so redundant to media queries? and also if your page exceeds the viewport you should get a scroll bar by default